# C++ No Main class found in NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I imported an existing C++ project into Netbeans IDE, and i have this error

```
<No main classes found>
```

How i can make  a class main in C++?

Update:

This the project i try to import https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig

Thank you

Comment: Did you set your project properties to C++? Sounds like a Java project error to me.

Comment: Does your project contain the source file that has the `main` function?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++ but i think it xmrig.cpp.. how i can point to netbeans that this class is the main?? here's the project source https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/tree/master/  Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main()
{

   return 0;
}
```

Will always be your main class

Comment: can you show me how to point to netbeans that this class is the main? thank you

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. And as the others have said it seems as if you are using a java compiler/java file and running c++ in it. If you search for <No main classes found> everything is java. Make sure you are running a c++ compiler and document as well as having a int main as stated above.